# Specifying conditional distribution in a Bayesian network

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, prior, bayesian-network

I am trying to learn about Bayesian networks and am really having a hard time to figure out how to setup some simple models.

Say, I have a model as:

```
A -> C <- B
```

i.e. `C` has `A` and `B` as parents. Now, A and B are discrete quantities and say $A \in [0, 1, 2]$ and $B \in [0, 1, 2]$. So, I have 9 possible combination of the states of A and B.

So, in the Bayesian network I can model the prior distributions over A and B as Dirichlet distributions.

Now, if I want to model this child node as a Gaussian conditioned on the parents, is it correct that I need to specify/estimate the parameters for these 9 conditional Gaussians i.e. $P(C|A=0, B=0), P(C|A=1, B=0) .... P(C|A=2, B=2)$

Also, I want to give it the full Bayesian treatment and specify priors over the mean and standard deviation of these Gaussians as well. Say I have some *limited* data. Is it ok to do something sample these subsets and initialize the prior over the mean using the mean from the data of the appropriate subset and set a large standard deviation (actually is there something else we can do for the std)?

I worry about this as I have peeked at the data to specify this prior and I wonder if this will bias the estimate. I plan to use something like MCMC for estimating the full posterior.

Additionally, what would happen if there is no data for one of the subset? What should one do for that case?

Sorry I know I am asking many questions in one post but been racking my brain with these thoughts for days now.